# prove that $\{A_1,...,A_m\}$ cannot span $M_{nn}$ if $\vec{0} \neq y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_1y=A_2y=...=A_my=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A_1, A_2,...,A_m$ denote n by n matrices if $\vec{0} \neq y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A_1y=A_2y=...=A_my=0$, prove that $\{A_1,...,A_m\}$ cannot span $M_{nn}$

**My Proof (Edited)**

Let $B \in M_{nn}$ and invertible. Now assume that $M_{nn} = span\{A_1, A_2,...,A_m\}$

$$B = c_1A_1 + ...+c_mA_m$$
$$By = [c_1A_1 + ...+c_mA_m]y$$
$$By = c_1A_1y + ...+c_mA_my = c_10+...+c_m0=0$$

Hence $By=0$. Since it is invertible $y = B^{-1}0 = 0$ which is a contradiction.

Is this approach (now) correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hence...either..." is false.

In general, $Ax=0$ does not imply that either $A=0$ or $x=0$.

---

Hint for a proof.

Let $B$ be an *invertiable* matrix of $M_{nn}$ and assume that $B$ is a linear combination of the matrices $A_k$. Calculate $By$.

Comment: I made an edit to the proof, if this correct now?

Comment: @A.RadekMartinez that's what the hint says. Correct. :)

Comment: @A.RadekMartinez: for "solutioin-verification" type question, you'd better keep your original attempt/proof/solution instead of erasing it, and "add" your new solution below if needed.